# Use more than 2 GB RAM in Dell OptiPlex 320

Tags: memory, dell-optiplex

A while ago I purchased 2 × 2 GB Sticks of RAM for my Dell OptiPlex 320. 
When I inserted them,
I was greeted with a series of beeps, and a system that would not boot. 
I checked each stick, and individually they work, just not as a pair.

If I insert one 2 GB and one 1 GB, then the BIOS detects both
(reporting 3 GB installed: 1 × 2 GB and 1 × 1 GB) and will boot,
but Windows (8.1.1) can utilise only 1 GB. 

How can I get both sticks to work, thus giving me 4 GB RAM?

- The sticks in question are identical Kingston KVR533D2N4/2G modules
  and do not have ECC.
- The system is a July 2007 one,
  and the technical specifications
  list it as being capable of using up to 4 GB.

Comment: 1. which version of windows, 2. did you check if your motherboard can handle 4 GB of ram from the manufactures specs?

Comment: @Sickest Win 8.1.1, yes, I did, read the OP

Comment: in memory overview it says this: NOTICE:
Do not install ECC memory modules. Doing so may cause the system not to boot or affect performance.

Comment: @Sickest I do not have ECC modules, I specifically made sure the ones I purchased were non-ECC

Comment: Bump, need to get this resolved...

Comment: Your problem description is vague and lacks details. For example, you say "BIOS detects both". What *precisely* does that mean? Did the BIOS report 3GB? And you say "Windows can only utilise 1GB". But you don't explain why you say that. What *precisely* did you see? You have to tell us the evidence you gathered, not the conclusions you drew from it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The BIOS reports 3GB installed, 1*2Gb and 1*1GB, when I boot windows, it only sees 1GB and can only use 1GB.

Comment: How did you determine that Windows only sees 1GB? Again, you are giving us conclusions rather than observations. What tools did you use? And what precisely did they report?

Comment: I used explorer, looked at the system specs=> 1GB RAM...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What would you suggest to check available RAM?

Comment: Bump @dav Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of the BIOS installed from Dell's website. We have a few 320's running here with 4GB of RAM.

Be sure the sticks match in specs, ie the same speed and both are non-ECC.

Comment: asking questions in your answer?

Comment: I have, although I will check, and it's a pair of identical Kingston "KVR533D2N4/2G" Sticks.

Comment: What month/year are the 320's you have?

Answer (score 0):

4 GB of RAM will work only if you have no graphics card. 
The 320 disables the 2nd RAM slot when a graphics card is present.

Answer (score -2):

Ues 2x 2GB DDR 2 of 667mhz only. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you [edit] you answer and explain *why* you are recommending this?